# Receiving carriage return through Serial Port

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, console-application

So I am developing a console application which is able to read and write to/from Arduino through Serial Port. At the moment I got a `switch` statement to read incoming data from Arduino and depending on the incoming data I will write to the Arduino a couple of messages.

```
string incoming = port.ReadExisting();
string questionMark = "?";
string carriageReturn = "\r";
string text = string.Empty;

switch (incoming)
    {
        case "@r\r":
            port.Write(questionMark+ "*" + carriageReturn);
            break;
        case "@{":
            port.Write("@" + text);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown command sent by the Arduino\n Command: " + incoming);
                break;
     }
```

Now, I am testing out the application with another application to read and write it and when I send to the console application the `"@r\r"` it will give

> Unknown command sent by the Arduino\n Command: "@r\r".

I've found the problem and it comes from the carriage return or `\r`.

Do you have any idea how could I solve this problem? I want to receive the carriage return because it is the end of it.

Comment: Have you set the `SerialPort.NewLine` property value?

Comment: Like this? `port.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: Does not make sense, you should not be able to see \n and \r in the console.  Those control characters affect console output as well.  Crystal ball says that your Arduino actually sent two characters, a backslash and an r.  Using ReadExisting() is also *very* wrong, you only get what is "existing" and that might well be only "@" or "@r".  Given that we can't trust your console output, that's the most likely failure mode.  Do this right and depend on the NewLine property so you can use ReadLine() instead.

Comment: So what should I do to improve my code to actually receive what I want? @HansPassant

Comment: You should implement a proper protocol.  A way to accurately detect that you got the full response.   A very simple protocol is using a unique character that is always the last character in the response.  Like NewLine.  Now you can use ReadLine() and trust that you'll get all of the characters in the response, not just some of them.  Arduino makes that easy as well with Serial.println().  Keep it simple.

Comment: Yes I understand what you're saying. But you are telling me to instead of using `SerialPort.ReadExisting` use `SerialPort.ReadLine()`? @HansPassant

Comment: `DataReceived` will be called **whenever there is any** input on the serial port. Thus, you have to make sure to handle **incomplete messages** gracefully. You need to buffer everything you get in `DataReceived` until you get a complete message. You can never assume that because you sent 3 bytes to the port, `DataReceived` will also receive the 3 bytes in one call.